# Angular - Forcing a reactive form to be valid in a unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular v4.4.4. In a component, after a button is clicked in the template, the form is saved assuming the reactive form is valid. Something like (pseudo-code):

```
public onSave(): void {
    if (this.myForm.valid) {
        this._createFoo();
    }
}

private _createFoo(): void {
    this._fooService.createItem(this.foo).subscribe(result => {
        // stuff happens...
    });
}
```

In the related unit test I need to force the form to be valid so I can confirm the service is being called. Something like this:

```
it('should create Foo', () => {
    const spy = spyOn(_fooService, 'createItem').and.callThrough();
    component.foo = new Foo();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const bookButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#bookButton'));
    expect(bookButton !== null).toBeTruthy('missing Book button');
    bookButton.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

This will fail because myForm is never set as valid.

In this particular case I do not want to give every input in the form a value. I just need to watch and see if the service subscription occurs. How can I force the form to be valid?

Comment: In this case, you should really create a unit test for the service and one for the component, so that they are separate. The component test should give a valid value and check the subscription, and the Service test should make sure the request is going through

Comment: In this case the value returned by the service is irrelevant. The spy is just confirming the service is called. The service itself is tested elsewhere.

Comment: I see. Is there a specific reason you don't want to put the values in directly? just to save time?

Comment: 1) Regardless of best practices, is this possible?
2) The form is long and complex. In this case form values are irrelevant since the test just confirms that a subscription is made to the correct service. Forcing the form to be valid makes sure the test focuses on what is important.

Comment: unfortunately I could not find anything and don't know the answer. Just keep updating your question and hopefully you'll get an answer, good luck

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why not just clear the validators list?

```
// If there are any async validators
//
this.myForm.clearAsyncValidators();
// If there are any normal validators
//
this.myForm.clearValidators();
// Doing the validation on all the controls to put them back to valid
//
this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
```

This will ensure your form has no validators, thus being valid.

Comment: I have:

                   this.newClientForm.clearAsyncValidators();
                    this.newClientForm.clearValidators();
                    this.newClientForm.updateValueAndValidity();

                    console.log(this.newClientForm.status);  --->"INVALID" 
:(

Answer (score 7):

If someone is still struggling with this:

As @[realappie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4047409/realappie) answer suggests, we should clear all sync/async validators. **But the validators in most cases are on the controls and not the form itself** . So, just loop all the controls perform this operation on each control.

From the test file it should look like:

```
const controls = component.myForm.controls;

for (const control in controls) {
    // Clear sync validators - use clearAsyncValidators() for async
    // validators
    controls[control].clearValidators();
    // should update just the control and not everything
    controls[control].updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true });
}
component.myForm.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Answer (score 5):

using only javascript, you can do:

```
      Object.defineProperty(comp.editForm, 'valid', {
        get: () => true
      });
```

to override the getter, to always return true.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making the form to be valid, we can spy on the **valid** property of the form group.

We can do like:

`spyOnProperty(component.supplierForm, 'valid').and.returnValue(false);`

This line of code return **true** whenever the **valid** property the form group (`this.myForm.valid`) is accessed and it helps to pass the test.